# Method selection for Android Navigation

Tags: android, navigation

I couldn't decide which method is better in my app for android navigation.
Both work, but since I am not familiar with application development principles, which do you think is better management?

---

- **My 1st method;**

This is how I created a class.

```
public class NavigationAction {
    private final View view;

    public NavigationAction(View view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    public void withoutArguments(int action) {
        Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(action);
    }

    public void withArguments(NavDirections action) {
        Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(action);
    }

}
```

This is how I access and navigate with databing in Layout

```
<data>

    <import type="app.mysample.R" />

    <import type="app.mysample.ui.navigation.NavigationAction" />

    <variable
        name="navigate"
        type="NavigationAction" />
    
    </data>
```

I am navigating in the toolbar as follows

```
app:navigationOnClickListener="@{() -> navigate.withoutArguments(R.id.action_global_to_menu)}"
```

---

- **My 2st method;**

I am creating a method inside the fragment

```
public void onClickToolbarBackButton(View v) {
    Navigation.findNavController(v).navigate(R.id.action_global_to_menu);
}
```

This is how I access and navigate with databing in Layout

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="aboutFragment"
        type="app.mysample.ui.fragment.menu.subclasses.AboutFragment" />

</data>
```

I am navigating in the toolbar as follows

```
app:navigationOnClickListener="@{() -> aboutFragment.onClickToolbarBackButton(toolbar)}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code analysis for the two methods you provided for Android navigation:

1. **First Method (Using `NavigationAction` Class)**:

   - **Pros**:

     - Centralized navigation logic can promote reusability across fragments.
     - Separation of navigation logic from the fragment which may lead to cleaner code.
   - **Cons**:

     - Might be a slight overhead for simple navigation tasks since you have to instantiate `NavigationAction`.
2. **Second Method (Directly Inside Fragment)**:

   - **Pros**:

     - Straightforward and intuitive. Someone reading the fragment can see the navigation logic directly.
     - No extra class or instantiation is required.
   - **Cons**:

     - Navigation logic is coupled with the fragment. If you have many fragments, you may end up writing similar code multiple times.

**Recommendation**:
If your app is expected to have complex navigation logic or if you anticipate reusing the same navigation actions across multiple fragments/views, the first method using `NavigationAction` might be beneficial. However, if your navigation requirements are simple and straightforward, the second method should suffice.